# MVC routing using Symfony routing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony5

Using symfony / routing, need to implement routing for the MVC application. Using the whole Symfony is prohibited, only the library.
Controller class:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Core\Controller;
class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function IndexAction(){
        $this->View->render('index');
    }

}
```

view class:

```
namespace App\Core;

namespace App\Core;

class View{

    public function render($viewName) {
        $viewAry = explode('/', $viewName);
        $viewString = implode(DS, $viewAry);
        if(file_exists('View/site' . $viewString . '.php')) {
            require 'View/site' . $viewString . '.php';
        } else {
            die('The view \"' . $viewName . '\" does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

and Index.php itself from which it all starts:

```
use App\Controllers\IndexController;

use App\Core\Routing;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

use App\Core\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('index', new Route('/', array(
    '_controller' => [IndexController::class, 'IndexAction']
)));

return $collection;
```

As a result of a request to the application through the postman, I get nothing, what's the problem?

Comment: Hii, one question please what is DS in this line `$viewString = implode(DS, $viewAry);` ?

Comment: ```define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);```

Comment: and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your front controller you are just defining the routes, but not actually processing the request, matching it to a controller or invoking it.

There is a section on this topic [in the manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html), it uses more symfony components, but can be of help.

You'd have to determine the requested route directly from `PATH_INFO` instead of using the `HttpFoundation` component, and then try to match the request to a route.

Here is a very crude implementation:

```
$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('index', new Route('/', array(
    '_controller' => [IndexController::class, 'IndexAction']
)));

$matcher = new UrlMatcher($collection, new RequestContext());

// Matcher will throw an exception if no route found
$match = $matcher->match($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

// If the code reaches this point, a route was found, extract the corresponding controller
$controllerClass = $match['_controller'][0];
$controllerAction = $match['_controller'][1];

// Instance the controller
$controller = new $controllerClass();
// Execute it
call_user_func([$controller, $controllerAction]);
```